# user verification is not working using jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt, token

I am learning to make a mern-jwt-auth app. The email is being sent perfectly but I cannot verify the email using token.

I am sorry if I cannot describe my problem properly. Here is the github repo: [text](https://github.com/bishwobista/mern-jwt-auth)

Firstly, a user goes to register page and registers with their account. An email is sent to the user. When the user clicks on the verify email, they go to: localhost:3000/verify/{token}.
But it says: Cannot GET /verify/{token}

The userSchema and tokenSchema are working fine. The token is same as in the mongodb collection.

*The client App.js file:
*

````
import SignUp from "./pages/SignUp";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import VerifyEmail from "./pages/VerifyEmail";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link , useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import SignIn from "./pages/SignIn";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path= '/'element={<PublicRoute><SignIn/></PublicRoute>  } />
          <Route path='/signup'element= { <PublicRoute><SignUp /></PublicRoute> } />
          <Route path='/home'element={<ProtectedRoute><Home /></ProtectedRoute>} />
          <Route path="/verify/:token" element={<PublicRoute><VerifyEmail /></PublicRoute>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

export function ProtectedRoute({ children }) {
  
  const data = localStorage.getItem("data");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  if (data) {
    return children;
  } else {
    useEffect(() => {
      navigate("/");
    }
    )
  }
}
export function PublicRoute({ children }) {
  const data = localStorage.getItem("data");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  if (!data) {
    return children;
  } else {
    useEffect(() => {
    navigate("/home");
    }
    )
    return null;
  }
}```

*config/api.js*

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/",
});

export default api;
```




The server folder structure is as follows:


*server.js
*```const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
const authRoute = require('./routes/authRoute');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
    }
    
);
dotenv.config();
connectDB();

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/auth', authRoute);


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`it's live at http://localhost:${port}`);
    }
);


```

*routes/authRoute.js
*```const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {registerUser, loginUser, userData, updateUser, verifyEmail} = require('../controllers/authController');

const authMiddleware = require('../config/authMiddleware');
router.post('/register', registerUser);
router.post('/login', loginUser);
router.get('/userdata', authMiddleware, userData);
router.post('/update',updateUser);
router.post('/verify-email', verifyEmail)
module.exports = router;```

*controllers/authController.js
*```const User = require("../models/UserModel");
const Token = require("../models/tokenModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mailSender = require("../config/mailSender");
const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (userExists) {
    return res
      .status(200)
      .send({ success: false, message: "User already exists" });
  } else {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    const newUser = await User.create({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: hash,
    });
    // const newUser = new User({ name, email, password });
    // await newUser.save();

    await mailSender(newUser, "verify-mail");
    
    return res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: "User registered" });
  }
};

const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      const tokenData = {
        id: user._id,
        user: user.name,
        email: user.email,
      };
      const token = jwt.sign(tokenData, "secret key", {
        expiresIn: "30d",
      });

      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ success: true, message: "User logged in", token: token });
    } else {
      return res.send({ success: false, message: "User not logged in" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send({ success: false, message: "User not logged in" });
  }
};

const userData = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).send({ success: true, data: req.body.user });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send({ success: false, error: error });
  }
};

const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { updateUser } = req.body;
  const email = updateUser.email;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(updateUser.cupassword, user.password))) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(15);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(updateUser.password, salt);

    try {
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {
        name: updateUser.name,
        email: updateUser.email,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });

      return res
        .status(200)
        .send({ success: true, msg: "Password updated successfully" });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({ msg: "Something went wrong" });
    }
  } else {
    return res.send({ msg: "No user or something went wrong" });
  }
};

const verifyEmail = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tokenDetail = await Token.findOne({ token: req.body.token });
    console.log(tokenDetail);
    if (tokenDetail) {
      await User.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: tokenDetail.userid,
        isVerified: true,
      });
      await Token.findOneAndDelete({ token: req.body.token });
      res.send({ success: true, msg: "Email verified Successfully" });
    } else {
      res.send({ success: false, msg: "Invalid Token" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  verifyEmail,
  userData,
  updateUser
};
```
*config/mailSender.js*
```const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const Token = require("../models/tokenModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

module.exports = async (data, mailType) => {
  try {
    const mailConfig = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.APP_EMAIL, // email
        pass: process.env.APP_PASSWORD, // Google App Password
      },
    });

    // Mail Verification
    const verifyToken = await bcrypt
      .hashSync(data._id.toString(), 10)
      .replaceAll("/", "");
    const token = new Token({ userid: data._id, token: verifyToken });
    await token.save();
    const content = `<h1>Please click on the link below to verify your account</h1>
             <a href="http://localhost:3000/verify/${verifyToken}">Verify Account</a>`;

    const mailOptions = {
      from: "bishwo5bista@gmail.com",
      to: data.email,
      subject: "Verify your mail for JWT App",
      html: content,
    };

    const info = await mailConfig.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log("Email sent:", info.response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```
````

Comment: I went through your git repo and it seems like your server and react both are running on same port. When you hit `localhost:3000/verify/{token}` it checks the GET request on server because you add proxy in client. Hence, there is no GET request for this endpoint on server and it cause `Cannot GET /verify/{token}`. 
Solution is change your server port and then try